# How to enable or install Mcrypt extension for Cake Php without xampp or etc.?

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, composer-php, mcrypt

I use php 7.4 and my os is macos monterey. I want to enable mcrypt extension, tried nano mypath/php.ini and search "extension" but nothing found. And i dont use xampp or etc. I use cake built-in server.

I install `brew install mcrypt`. I run "composer install" then i get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-mcrypt * but it is missing from your 
    system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
    - /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mcrypt` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

I see mcrypt in my brew list but how i supposed to do to enable mcrypt extension on php.ini or wherever ?

This is my brew list:

```
==> Formulae
    apr             curl            git             libidn2         libtool         mecab-ipadic    pcre            tidy-html5
    apr-util        fontconfig      gmp             libnghttp2      libunistring    memcached       pcre2           unixodbc
    argon2          freetds         groonga         libpng          libzip          mhash           php             webp
    aspell          freetype        icu4c           libpq           m4              msgpack         php@7.4         zstd
    autoconf        gd              jpeg            libsodium       mariadb         oniguruma       readline
    brotli          gettext         krb5            libssh2         mcrypt          openldap        rtmpdump
    ca-certificates giflib          libevent        libtiff         mecab           openssl@1.1     sqlite
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cake built-in server"? If Composer tells you do edit any of the two files in `/opt/homebrew`, it looks like you are using a PHP binary installed through Brew

Comment: I mean sudo ./cake server --port 80 -H localhost;